# JS, mapping through an array for filtering when it has the same value of another array

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, filter, include

I have a problem: Js map filter array and loops

I have two arrays of ObjectsID (favorite and inCommon). I map through the first one to to check when it has the same value of another array, so then the value it's added to a state (the state is working).

If the second array (inCommon) has only ONE value this code is working, but I don't know how to do when the second array has more than one value (I was thinking loops maybe?)
Thanks for anyone willing to help

```
const [favorite, setFavorite] = useContext(FavoriteContext);
const [ cart, setCart ] = useContext(CartContext);
favorite and cart array= [{_id: '', name: ''}, {}]
const addToCart = (favorite) => {
    const checkedCart = cart.map(item => item._id)
    let checkedFavorite = favorite.map(item => item._id)
    const inCommon = checkedFavorite.filter(item => checkedCart.includes(item))
    favorite.map(item => {if(item._id !== inCommon.toString()) 
      {setCart((prev) => {return [item, ...prev]})
      console.log(item._id)
    }})
  }
```

Comment: where is data arrays?

Comment: cart and favorite are in a state

Comment: add data arrays also. What I meant

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the bug is in `if(item._id !== inCommon.toString())`, `inCommon` is an Array and when it has only 1 element it will return the value, but when it has more than one items it will return comma seperated values like `id1,id2,id3...` .

you can use `includes()` like you already are in `item => checkedCart.includes(item)`

```
if( !inCommon.includes(item._id)){...}
```